# ¿Porque Label con stringvar desaparece cuando se lo llama desde un command de otra ventana?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

el problema que tengo consiste en que cuando ejecuto esto

```
def ventanaCondiciones():
    global textoCondiciones , comboSimbolos

    ventanaPpal= Tk()
    marco = Frame(ventanaPpal , width=300 ,height=300)
    marco.pack(side="bottom")
    marco.config(bd=25)
    bonos=['A2E7D','A2E8','A2E8D','A2J9','A2J9D','A2M2','A2M6','AA19','AA19D','AA21','AA21D','AA22','AA25','A25D','AA26','AA26D','AA37','AA37D','AA46','AA46D','AC17','AC17D','AE48','AE48D','AF19','AF20','AF20D','AJ19','AL36','AM18','AM19','AM20','AMX8','AMX9','AN18','AN18D','AO20','AO20D','AS17','AY24','AY24D','BADER','BARX1','BCOR1','BCOR3','BCOR4','BD2C6','BD2C9','BD4C6','BD6C6','BDC18','BDC19','BDC20','BDC22','BDEDD','BDEE','BNY14','BOTE2020','BP18','BP21','BP28','BPC3O','BPLD','BPLDD','BPLE','BPMD','BPMDD','BPME','BT02','BT03','CCH1','CEDA','CEDI','CH24D','CHAQ','CHSG1','CHSG2','CL2F9','CLM19','CO17','CO26','CO26D','CS8HO','CUAP','DIA0','DIA0D','DICA','DICAD','DICE','DICP','DICY','DICYD','DIE0','DIP0','DIY0','DIY0D','ERD16','FORM3','GD05','GE17','GJ17D','GO06','GS27','I15G8','I16Y8','I17O8','I19D8','I19S8','I21J8','I21N8','L2A19','L2DE7','L2M19','LB2F9','LB2M9','LB3F9','LBA19','LBM19','LBO19','LBS19','LBY19','LTPD8','LTPE9','LTPN8','LTPO8','MPC7O','NDG1','NF18','NO20','NRH1','NRH2','O.N INDUPA C. 4','OACI8','OAEY1','OAOY2','OCEY1','OCIR6','OCR10','OCSY2','ODNM1','ODNY9','OGBY1','OGCO1','OHIY5','OINV1','OIRS9','OIRX6','OIRY7','OMPE9','OMRP1','OMRP4','ONARCOR6','ONARCOR7','ONAXION1','ONAXION2','ONCRE_XIX','ONCRE_XX','ONESTRA1','ONIRSA7','ONNEWSA6','ONPAE3','ONPAE4','ONPCR_3','ONPEPASA_6','ONPTR_C4','ONPTR_C5','ONPTR_VCP11','ONY13','ONYPF_38','ONYPF_40','ONYPF_45','OPNY1','ORAY3','OTRY8','OTY11','OYP18','PAA0','PAA0D','PAP0','PARA','PARAD','PARE','PARP','PARY','PARYD','PAY0','PAY0D','PBA25','PBE17','PBF17','PBF23','PBG16','PBJ21','PBJ27','PBM24','PBY13','PBY17','PBY22','PF23D','PMD18','PMG18','PMJ21','PMN18','PMY16','PMY24','PNC8O','PR10','PR11','PR13','PR15','PR16','PRE3','PRE4','PRE5','PRE6','PRE8','PRE9','PRO1','PRO2','PRO4','PRO5','PRO6','PRO8','PRO9','PUL26','PUM21','PUO19','RHC20','RNG11','RNG21','RNG22','RNG23','S12A9','S22F9','S28F0','S28F9','S28J9','S29M9','S30A0','S30A9','S30S9','S31L0','S31O9','S31Y9','SA24D','SARH','TC20','TC21','TC23','TC25P','TDEC','TFU27','TGB81','TJ20','TM18','TN20','TO21','TO23','TO26','TPAG4','TPAG5','TRCRO','TS18','TSCH6','TUCS1','TUCS2','TUCS3','TVPA','TVPE','TVPP','TVPY','TVPYD','TVY0','TY03','TY04','TY05','U2G9D','U2S9D','UG9D','X22F9','X31Y9','YCA9O','YCADO','YPCNO','YPCTO','YPCUO','YPCZO']
    textoCondiciones = Text(marco)
    textoCondiciones.pack()
    textoCondiciones.config(width=70,height=21)
    texto = StringVar()
    texto.set("Seleccione el bono que desea consultar y presione 'Ver prospecto'")
    etiqueta = Label(ventanaPpal, textvariable=texto)
    etiqueta.place(x=25,y=20)
    botonVer = Button(ventanaPpal , text="Ver prospecto" , command=condiciones).place(x=300 , y=45)

    ventanaPpal.title("TradingTools - Condiciones de emisión")
    ventanaPpal.resizable(0,0)
    comboSimbolos = ttk.Combobox(ventanaPpal)
    comboSimbolos.place(x=50 , y=50)

    comboSimbolos['values'] = bonos
    comboSimbolos.current(0)
    ventanaPpal.geometry("720x480")
    ventanaPpal.mainloop()
```

obtengo esto donde el texto seleccione... se muestra[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
sin embargo cuando importo esto desde otro lugar algo asi

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from bonos.bono import ventanaCondiciones #<---esta es la niña
from alarmas.alarma import alarma
from indicadores.indicadores_bono import indicadores

program="principal"
root = Tk()
root.title("TradingTools")

if program == "principal":
    menubar = Menu(root, tearoff=0)
    root.config(menu=menubar, width=480 , height=320)
    archivo = Menu(menubar , tearoff=0)
    edit = Menu(menubar , tearoff=0)
    herramientas = Menu(menubar , tearoff=0)
    bonos = Menu(herramientas , tearoff=0)
    acciones = Menu(herramientas , tearoff=0)
    registro = Menu(herramientas , tearoff=0)
    ayuda = Menu(menubar , tearoff=0)
    nuevo = Menu(archivo , tearoff=0)
    abrir = Menu(archivo , tearoff=0)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo" , menu=archivo)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Editar" , menu=edit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Herramientas" , menu=herramientas)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Ayuda" , menu=ayuda)
    archivo.add_cascade(label="Nuevo" , menu=nuevo)
    archivo.add_cascade(label="Abrir" , menu=abrir)
    nuevo.add_command(label="Trade")
    nuevo.add_command(label="Notas")
    abrir.add_command(label="Trade")
    abrir.add_command(label="Notas")
    herramientas.add_cascade(label="Bonos" , menu=bonos)
    #Aqui es donde llamo la funcion!!!
    bonos.add_command(label="Condiciones de emisión" , command=ventanaCondiciones) 
    bonos.add_command(label="Curvas de rendimientos")
    bonos.add_command(label="Técnicos y flujo de fondos" , command=indicadores)
    herramientas.add_cascade(label="Acciones" , menu=acciones)
    acciones.add_command(label="Gráficos")
    acciones.add_command(label="Fundamentales")
    herramientas.add_separator()
    herramientas.add_command(label="Alarmas" , command=alarma)
    herramientas.add_cascade(label="Registro de Operaciones" , menu=registro)
    root.mainloop()
```

sucede esto, desaparece el label con el texto "Seleccione el bono..."
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
agradeceria una ayuda

Comment: Probablemente está relacionado con el uso de la variable global `textoCondiciones` ¿Para qué necesitas esa variable global? ¿No puede ser local, o un atributo de la clase o un parámetro que reciba la función?

Comment: textCondiciones es un campo de texto que necesita ser global para que acceda otra funccion que no la inclui porque no tiene nada qye ver con el problema, es una funcion que baja cosas de internet y las inserta en textoCondiciones, por eso es global esta y comboSimbolos para hacer uso de combo.get() en la otra funcion que no aparece
el problema es en esta variable
    texto = StringVar()
    --->texto.set("Seleccione el bono que desea consultar y presione 'Ver prospecto'") esto es lo que desaparece
    etiqueta = Label(ventanaPpal, textvariable=texto)
    etiqueta.place(x=25,y=20)

Comment: Pues precisamente... si tienes dos funciones que ambas pueden acceder a la misma variable global y poner cosas en ella, ¿cómo sabes que no es esa segunda función que no has mostrado la que está "borrando" el texto que pusiste desde la primera? No es buena idea en general usar variables globales como forma de compartir datos entre funciones. Es mejor usar parámetros, y sobre todo diseñar el código de modo que no haya dos funciones a la vez (en diferentes hilos) actuando sobre una misma variable.

Comment: Sin probar nada, parece que estás usando dos `mainloops`. El segundo se bloquea y por eso no actualiza nada. Reescribe el código para que sólo haya un mainloop.

Comment: pero no es el caso abulafia, estoy mas que seguro que esa variable global no tiene nada que ver con el problema

Comment: ChemaCortes y como podria entonces hacer que se abra otra ventana, es decir otra Tk usando un solo mainloop?